# Log4j 2.8 appears to iterate over collection parameter instead of calling toString

Tags: log4j2

It appears to me that Log4j is attempting to do something intelligent when collections are passed as parameters instead of simply calling toString().

Observe the following code for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<String> x = TreeMultiset.create(); //From Guava
    x.add("John");
    x.add("John");
    x.add("John");
    x.add("Dummy");
    System.out.println(x);
    LOG.info("People {}", x);
    LOG.info("People {}", x.toString());
}
```

Here LOG is basically the logger from log4j LogManager. This gives the following output.

```
[Dummy, John x 3]
2018-02-16 09:57:42,804 INFO main [MyClass] People [Dummy, John, John, John]
2018-02-16 09:57:42,806 INFO main [MyClass] People [Dummy, John x 3]
```

I was expecting the last line of output in the log line but I now have [Dummy, John, John, John .... ] in my log files.

On close inspection the culprit seems to be org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter#recursiveDeepToString which has the code

```
private static void recursiveDeepToString(final Object o, final StringBuilder str, final Set<String> dejaVu) {
        if (appendSpecialTypes(o, str)) {
            return;
        }
        if (isMaybeRecursive(o)) {
            appendPotentiallyRecursiveValue(o, str, dejaVu);
        } else {
            tryObjectToString(o, str);
        }
    }
```

The appendPotentiallyRecursiveValue simply iterates through the Collection instead of calling .toString()

My question is: Is this really necessary? (Or even dangerous?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good find. This behavior is actually not specific to Log4j 2.8, it has been in the code base since alpha versions of Log4j2.

So, why is Log4j doing this? The short answer is that this is a safety measure. Imagine this code:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(list); // add list to itself 

// option 1: what does this print?
System.out.println(list);

// option 2: what does this print/log?
logger.info(“list contents: {}”, list);
```

The first example (which internally calls `toString` on the list), will hang until it blows up with a stack overflow error.

The second example, logging the same list with Log4j will print something reasonable. And, more importantly, it will not die.

This may be a trivial example but in real applications self-references are not always easy to prevent. Users like it if logging an object doesn’t kill their application in production even when they made a mistake. :-)